# Code::Blocks console program problems on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, codeblocks, iterm

I usually do console application programs in CodeBlocks for algorithm problems and have recently switched to an OSX Mountain Lion machine. After installing xCode and CodeBlocks SP1 I have a problem.

When I run a program, a console terminal should appear with the output. This code was in the preferences, but it does not do it's job:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "$SCRIPT"' -e 'end tell'
```

Is there a possibility I could launch an iTerm2 window?

Answer (score 0):

osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm"' -e 'make new terminal' -e 'tell the first terminal' -e 'activate current session' -e 'launch session "Default Session"' -e 'tell the last session' -e 'write text  "$SCRIPT"' -e 'end tell' -e 'end tell' -e 'end tell'

Comment: Maybe you can explain your answer to make it more understandable?

Comment: I should say clearly in my answer, sorry. This question has two subquestions, one is his code not works, the other is for using iTerm2. Since I don`t use Terminal.app, I cannot fix his code. and for the second subquestion, it is possible, only need is put my answer in CodeBlock preferences. @RobinEllerkmann